# Range of a projectile as a function of launch angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile, distance

**Goal: Derive an equation for range of a projectile as a function of launch angle if it started from a height > 0 and landed to height = 0**

I know that the horizontal range
$$ R = \frac{v_0^2 \sin2\theta}{g} \tag1$$
refers to the range of a projectile which landed on the same vertical position as it started from.

But how to derive the range of a projectile as a function of launch angle if it started from a height $h > 0$ and landed to $h = 0$? I know that the formula $R = v_0 \cos\theta t$ is a good formula to start with in order to derive a range equation like (1), but considering that the path is not symmetric, is this goal achievable? Or is there already an equation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The horizontal displacement $x$ is given by
$$x=v_0t\cos\theta$$ where $v_0$ is the initial speed and $t$ is the time.

Meanwhile, the vertical position is given by $$y=-\dfrac{1}{2} gt^2 + v_0 t\sin\theta + h
.$$ where $h$ is the inital launch height.

You've got yourself a system of equations, namely,
$$
\left\{ 
x=v_0t\cos\theta \atop
y=-\dfrac{1}{2} gt^2 + v_0 t\sin\theta + h
\right.
$$

Solve the $x=v_0t\cos\theta$ equation for $t$ then substitute into second equation. You now have a relationship between $x$ and $y$. Note that the range is obtained when $y=0$, so set $y=0$, and you have your range equation.

Comment: And no, this is not a 'homework style problem' -- this is not phrased like a HW question, but rather inquires about the relevant equations.

Comment: I followed your method and I solved for x, and I got
$$ R = \frac{-B \sqrt{B^2 - 4(A)(C)}}{2A} $$
where $$A = \frac{-g}{2v_0^2 cos^2\theta} $$
$$ B = tan\theta $$
$$C= h$$
Is this what you want to write also?

Comment: Ah, there is a slight error in my comment. The R is $$ R = \frac{-B \pm \sqrt{B^2 - 4AC}}{2A} $$

Comment: for $A=\dfrac{g}{2v_0^2 \cos^2\theta}$, $B=-\tan\theta$ and $C=-h$, $R=\dfrac{-B\pm\sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}$.

Comment: So yes, your equation is correct too (we just flipped signs :).

Comment: Of course, you'd discard the negative solution. Lastly, if this fully answers your question, please consider 'accepting' the answer.

Comment: I'd also suggest to reduce this equation to Eq (1) as stated in your question for practice (by setting $h=0$, and using the $+$ solution).

Comment: Ah, so I would not be including initial height in the calculation?

Comment: Initial height is included in the calculations. When $h\neq 0$, your solution is obtained by the equation you typed in the comments. For the particular case where $h=0$, that same equation simplifies to $R=\frac{v_0^2 \sin2\theta}{g}$.

Comment: In regards with A, B, and C, why do you have different signs with them? Did you equate these into the right of the quadratic equation? And lastly, can we have a range equation for the case in my post wherein we can eliminate the initial velocity so that there is only one non-numerical component in the equation (the dependent variable or launch angle)?

Comment: BTW, thank you! I am accepting this answer, too.

Comment: The initial speed is required in the calculations. As for the signs of $A$, $B$ and $C$, our answers are equivalent. The quadratic you had started with $\dfrac{-g}{2v_0^2\cos^2\theta}$. I divided my equation by $-1$ such that my leading term is positive.