# Knowing if a projectile will hit a net given only distance and height of the net

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

Im trying to code a simulation which in which a cannon shoots a human in an arc into a vertical net and i only have the following info:

-The distance between the cannon and the net.
-The height of said net.

And i want to determine what are the values of the inicial velocity and the firing angle for the human to land safely on the net.
I cant for the life of me use the expressions that i learned in my physics class to solve this and so that i can begin programming.

I have an exemple which is if the net is at a distance of 40 m and has a height of 5 m what are the values for the inicial velocity and the angle.

Comment: Projectile motion; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion

Comment: You are neglecting drag, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would refer you to my post here as to the derivation of the equation I am about to present: [Range of a projectile as a function of launch angle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/601203/range-of-a-projectile-as-a-function-of-launch-angle/601206?noredirect=1#comment1352561_601206).

Based on the following system of equations,
$$
\left\{ 
x=v_0t\cos\theta \atop
y=-\dfrac{1}{2} gt^2 + v_0 t\sin\theta + h
\right.
$$

Variables: $y$ is the y-position; $x$ is x-position; $v_0$ is initial launch speed; $\theta$ is launch angle; $h$ is initial launch height (height when $t=0$), $g=9.8\; \rm m/s^2$.

I solve for $t$ in the first equation and substitute it into Eq. (2).

$$y = -\dfrac{1}{2} g\left({x \over v_0 \cos\theta}\right)^2 + v_0 \left({x \over v_0 \cos\theta}\right)\sin\theta + h$$

I therefore obtain,

$$\implies y = -\dfrac{g}{2v_0^2 \cos^2\theta} x^2 + x\tan\theta + h \tag{*}$$

Equation (*) describes the trajectory of your ball -- the $y$ position as a function of the $x$ position.

You can thus use it to model your simulation.

Projectile 2-D motion is quite nice to work with -- it's easy to work with a trajectory function like $y(x)$.

EDIT: note that for your case $(x=40, y=5)\rm \; m$, you will have infinitely many solutions for your launch angle $\theta$ and initial speed $v_0$.

The plot below shows all the possible values of $v_0$ and $\theta$ that guarantee the human passes through the point $(40,5)$.

[image]

Comment: Yeah thats what i find so weird, that there are infinite possibilities of combinations if we are only given distance and height of the net there must be something wrong or that im not understanding in the assignment i shall ask my teacher for clarification

I cant thank you enough for all the work you put into answering my question. Thank you so much for helping me i was really lost.

Comment: It's actually not too weird -- the $y = -\dfrac{g}{2v_0^2 \cos^2\theta} x^2 + x\tan\theta + h$ equation, once you plug in all your known variables, will have 2 variables left -- $\theta$ and $v_0$. Therefore, you will get infinitely many solutions (because infinitely many pairs of $\theta$ and $v_0$ will satisfy the equation. 



In order to get just 1 solution, you must either have a second condition (equation) to satisfy (e.g. minimizing the launch speed, in which case $\theta = 45^\circ$), or simply pick one set of values that you like.

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped. If it fully answered your question, I would highly appreciate if you 'accepted' the answer ;)